# kohana registration returns error

Tags: kohana-3, kohana-orm, kohana-auth

I have working registration script the only problem is that i do not know how to check if username already exist because now if email or username already exist it returns me this fatal error: `ORM_Validation_Exception [ 0 ]: Failed to validate array ~ MODPATH/orm/classes/kohana/orm.php [ 1174 ]`

And here is my script:

```
$validate = Validation::factory($values)
        ->rule('name', 'not_empty')
        ->rule('password', 'matches', array(':validation', 'password', 'repeat-password'))
        ->rule('password', 'not_empty')
        ->rule('email', 'email')->rule('email', 'not_empty')
if(!$validate->check()){
    $errors = $validate->errors('registration', true);
    foreach($errors as $value){
        echo $value . "<br />";
    }
    return;
}
$model = ORM::factory('user');
$model->values(array(
    'username'          => $values['name'],
    'email'             => $values['email'],
    'password'          => $values['password'],
    'password_confirm'  => $values['repeat-password'],
));
```

Im using 3.2 version.

Comment: Why you don't use ORM built in validation? Create your rules in the model and try-catch when saving. Check out the docs for more information.

Comment: Why does Kohana not give a more descriptive error, e.g. Duplicate key. This error description is so ugly. I know now how to handle validation, but can't the default error description be more meaningful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out if an entry exists...

```
$model = ORM::factory('user', $values['name']);

if ( !$model->is_loaded() ) {
    // do registration
}
```

This will try to search for a user model with that username (if it is set to your primary key).